# Submit button outside reactive form is not working

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Consider the following form in a Angular component called app-catalog:

```
<form [formGroup]="catalogForm" (ngSubmit)="save()">

   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let section of sections?.controls; let i = index">
        <app-section [index]="i" [sectionForm]="section"></app-section>
      </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Now in my page, I call the component and add a submit button below :

```
 <app-catalog #catalog></app-catalog>

 <button type="submit" class="btn-save button primary" [disabled]="catalog.catalogForm.invalid || 
    !catalog.catalogForm.dirty" form="catalog.catalogForm">Save from outside</button>
```

The disabled state is working just fine, so accessing the form attributes is not a problem

However clicking the button does nothing. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Sam I think button type submit was not able to locate form element to trigger submit action. why don't you keep type="button" and add (click)="submitForm()" custom function
like in this https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-interacts-with-child-via-local-variable

Comment: the button must belong to the "form" (must be inside the `<form>...</form>`. You can simply write in your button `<button (click)="save(catalog.catalogForm)">`

Comment: So based on your recommendations I change the type of the button to "button" and I added `(click)="catalog.save()"`. This seems to work fine. Thank you !